# Improbable Inequalities

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

I'm making a work decision, and in my as I weigh the digits {0-9} as they pertain to this particular situation, I find:

In one case, this is true:

```
    1 < 7 < 4 < {2=3=5} < {0=6=9} < 8
```

In another, similar case, this is true:

```
    1 < 7 < 4 < 3 < {2=5=6=9} < {0=8}
```

> What specific choice am I making a decision about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is

> when you try to write them in seven-segment display, you sort them by the number of strokes.
>
>  [image]

And also

> when you try to write them in sixteen-segment display instead.
>
>  [image]

So I'm guessing

> that you are trying to build a (light) device or a simple "digit boards" (like those birthday candles) where you want to make sure it's less energy consuming or lighter in weight.

Comment: That's the first one, but what about the second?

Comment: @Deusovi I just realized that the second one is not the same answer (maybe just another variant), but both of them should be different answers!

Comment: Ah, nice job spotting that! I had the first one pretty much immediately, but I couldn't figure out which version of it worked for the second.

Comment: Well, that tells us, what the numbers are about. It does not answer the question  what specific choice the OP has to make. For what choice does he need to sort the digits this way? Or is it simply rot13(Juvpu qvfcynl-glcr fubhyq v hfr sbe zl arj cebqhpg)?

Comment: Welp my bad.. I'm actually in the middle of trying to sleep.. PSE is such a great distraction..

Comment: It seems like that question is a bit "what am I thinking of?" whereas the question "what are the numbers about?" is one that has a definitely-correct answer. (Incidentally, I was in the same boat as Deusovi.)

Comment: I was going for Rot13(V'z gelvat gb qrpvqr juvpu glcr bs qvfcynl gb hfr). Well done, and your checkmark is forthcoming.