# Reversical Engineerimicating

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, real

Ok, like, OMG!, this is totally true.

I was looking through an old Notepad++ file I had and saw the following statements, verbatim, as I found them:

```
hours max cats = {1,0} 14 or {_,8} 11
minTen max cat = {0} 10
minOne max cat = {8} 11
        MAX CATS EVER: 35 {10:08}
0 10    6   10
1 4     2   3
2 7     5   8
3 7     5   7
4 7     4   5
5 7     5   8
6 9     6   8
7 5     3   4
8 11    7   10
9 9     6   8
```

I immediately knew what they were for, but it took me awhile to reverse engineer what everything meant; how it all worked.

I said to myself, "Self! this might be a puzzle for my colleagues at PSE!"

I replied, "Probably not much of one, but what the hell?"

> Can you tell me to any degree of specificality what this does?

Comment: (note to self: I have too much time on my hands)

Comment: +1 from me simply because I run into these kinds of things all the time going through old files but never thought of making a puzzle out of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be a sketch for this puzzle:

> [Improbable Inequalities](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/87898/28719)

Well to be fair, they are not similar. But the concept is the same:

> They want to decide which type of segment-display to use for maybe a clock.

**This is *probably* the puzzle OP wanted to post:**

> I'm currently working as a designer for a huge segment-display clock. I really like cats, and I noticed that they are attracted to the neon lights from the clock. (Hey, they are warm enough so the cats will sleep above them!)
>
>  Let's assume that the number of cats is proportional to the number of segments of the clock which are on. For example, if we are using seven-segment-display, the number $3$ will attract $5$ cats as $3$ is written with $5$ segments.
>
>  There are $3$ types of segment-display: [seven-segment-display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-segment_display), [sixteen-segment-display](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixteen-segment_display), and extended seven-segment-display where each vertical segment is twice longer. If I can choose any type for each digit of the clock I'm working on, **at what time there will be the maximum number of attracted cats**, assuming it shows in $12$ hours format?

And the solution will be:

> At **10:08**, as it will attract $35$ cats using the extended seven-segment-display for all digits.

Completing Enzo's answer:

> The header is the solution for the puzzle, OP wants to find the maximum number of cats for each the hours and minutes independently, where specifically there are $2$ cases for hours: either $\geq 10$ or $< 10$.
>
>  The table below tells **the digit**, the cat attracted to **extended seven-segment-display**, **seven-segment-display**, and **sixteen-segment-display** respectively.

Post note:

> The extended seven-segment-display is actually not official. I probably missed other types of segment display to match with the numbers, but couldn't find one. ><

Comment: [I actually made it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Uwy9.png). rot13(Rirel zvahgr, haarpprffnel pngf jnyx bss gur obggbz bs gur fperra, naq arj pngf rzretr sebz gur "png ubhfr.")

Comment: @Chowzen I must admit, I'm a bit disappointed that the answer requires esoteric knowledge of another puzzle. But I suppose it couldn't be helped given the circumstances of how the puzzle was created. And I also suppose somebody running a search for "cat clock" on puzzling.SE on a lark and turning up the decoder ring isn't unthinkable. I *did*, of course, waste a good 20 minutes wracking my brain trying to find some significance to "cats" as an abbreviation, acronym, or computer programming term. >____<

Comment: @COTO I don't believe that knowledge of the other puzzle was necessary.

Comment: @Chowzen If that's the case, where does the "cats attracted by the neon lights on digital clocks" come from? Just a blue-sky guess that happened to be correct? I'm not bitter or anything, it's just that I couldn't figure out what on Earth cats had to do with digital clocks. Maybe cat fascination with clocks is insider knowledge for cat owners.

Comment: @COTO that part is fully my interpretation, of course it may be possibly wrong so I wrote "probably" there.. the answers are not related to the previous puzzle at all - except that I noticed they shared the same theme of segment display. I could write this answer without mentioning or have any preknowledge of previous question tbf. But yeah this is just my thought.

Comment: Based on his comment above, it seems he was thinking of training cats to *be* the segments of the clock, but since I'm a dog person and can't bear to think of cats as being useful in any regard, I much prefer your interpretation. ;)

Comment: @COTO Dog people are Great!. I am a Dog Person. athin got the correct answer.

Comment: Maybe I have an advantage tho since I'm a cat person, mew~ :3

Answer (score 4):

Partial answer:

> It's something related to a digital clock.

Analysing the header:

> The first line sets the hours of the clock. The two values in brackets separated by commas are the digits in the hour field, so `{1, 0}` represents 10 o'clock.
>  
>  The second and the third line set the minutes of the clock. The values in brackets are the digits in the minute field, so `{0}` in the second line and `{8}` in the third line represents 8 minutes.
>  
>  These three lines combined, therefore, represents 10:08 (the value in brackets on the fourth line).
>  
>  The meaning of the value on the right is still unknown, but when added together they generate the value of the fourth line, after the phrase **MAX CATS EVER**. Since the number on the right of `{1, 0}` is $14$, on the right of `{0}` is $10$ and on the right of `{8}` is $11$, the sum of these numbers is $14 + 10 + 11 = 35$.

Analysing the body:

> The first column are values ranging from 0 to 9, so they represent a digit. The third column represents the number of segments needed to represent the digit of the first column on a 7-segment display, like in [this image](https://www.rfwireless-world.com/images/7-segment-Display.jpg). The second and the fourth column are still unknown to me.

Comment: The oracle asks: "Thou devines the essence. How dost thou devine the numerical specifics?"
(I never played  DND, but I would have liked it.)

Comment: It may be worth noting that the numbers in the `min` (minute) equations are the 1st and 2nd entries for two rows in the table, and these two rows have the highest values in the second column. Hence the `=` probably isn't "setting" a value but is instead recording the 1st/2nd column data from the two columns with a _max_imum second column value.

Comment: I think it's different digital representations. I know there are ones that are different from the 7 segment display. 14 and 15 for example. It might be figuring out the time with the most bits switched on across different displays b

Comment: The third column seems close to 16-seg instead of 7-seg, but some of the numbers (e.g. 10 instead of 8 for 0) don't quite line up